# Как получить URi ImageView или как сохранить ссылку на картину в БД SQLite

Tags: android

Всем привет
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, из-за отсутствия опыта)
Не могу получить ссылку изображения из ImageView.

В общем ситуация такова.
Пользователь указывает желаемую картинку, для загрузки в ImageView через галерею. Картинка загружается, все ок. Теперь все нужно сохранить в БД. Все ок, кроме картинки. Как мне сохранить ссылку на нее, что бы я смог загрузить ссылку с БД в ImageView в следующий раз?

Так вызывается галерея

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
```

Так загружается выбранная картинка

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    Bitmap galleryPic = null;

    switch (requestCode) {
    case GALLERY_REQUEST:           
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {              
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            try {
                galleryPic = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Pic1.setImageBitmap(galleryPic);    
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: А если хранить надо не ссылку, а саму картинку?

Answer (score 1):

Сохраняйте в базе **Uri selectedImage**

```
selectedImage.ToString() -> Сохранить

selectedImage = Uri.parse(строки из базы);
```

Comment: А обратно загружать как?

Comment: try {
                galleryPic = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                 Pic1.setImageBitmap(galleryPic); 
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }